# Multiple if/then arguments in PHP for HTML classes

Tags: php, html

I would like to have an if/then argument for 2 classes (from the css) for a menu item. One where the menu item is blue if it is NOT the active page, and one where the menu item is red if it IS the active page. I have figured out the active page portion, now I am trying to figure out the if it is not active portion. I hope that makes sense. I have included a code snippit below.

```
<ul class="menu ul">
  <li><a class="Blue <?php if($page =='home'){echo 'active';}?>" href="../index.php" >Home</a></li>
```

I have tried multiple variations, however I cannot figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I understood you want to add different classes to link depending on $page variable.
for this i would recommend you to just use else statement

```
  <ul class="menu ul">
  <li><a class="<?php if($page =='home'){echo 'Blue';}else{echo 'Red';} ?>" href="../index.php" >Home</a></li>`
```

However it would be much better to check state of $page somewhere up (to not make spagetti code). And then echo only class in the a element.

```
 <?php if($page =='home'){$menu_class='Blue';}else{$menu_class= 'Red';};?>
 <ul class="menu ul">
  <li><a class="<?php echo $menu_class; ?>" href="../index.php" >Home</a></li></pre>
```

Comment: THe first item you presented makes perfect sense, and worked perfectly. I would like to be most efficient, and not have "spaghetti code" as you say. I have 23 items in a vertical side menu arrangement. Of these 23, 3 have the "blue" variable all the time and red when "active. I also want all 20 other items to have the "active" attribute when the page is in use. Should I use the second option them as well? and hoo would it look, given that theres the 23 items like this?

Comment: `<?php if($page =='home'){$menu_class='Blue';}else{$menu_class= 'Red';}if($page =='page2'){$menu_class='Red';}?>
<ul class="menu ul">
<li><a class="<?php echo $menu_class; ?>" href="../index.php" >Home</a></li></pre>`

Comment: 1. taking about items that have "blue" all the time -  just add it to html and don't ask php for it    
2. create helper function to check if you need to add red -> inside this function create array with names of pages which could be active -> use in_array to return red if true    
3. create another helper function to check if item is active -> add another array with possible active items to check if current page equals to them    
4. call echo on functions consistently to output classes into html

Answer (score 1):

Oleksandr is correct: It's better to have your links styles blue by default and overwrite it with the `active` class.

If you would want to give a hyperlink either one class or the other based on a simple condition, I would recommend this syntax:

```
<ul class="menu ul">
    <li>
        <a class="<?= $page == 'home' ? 'active' : 'Blue' ?>" href="../index.php" >Home</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The example above uses the [ternary operator](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-ternary-operator/) and the [echo shortcut syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), and simply echoes one of two values based on the outcome of the condition.